# What is the algorithm used by Curve fitting tool using a polynomial model in Matlab

Tags: algorithm, matlab, curve-fitting

I am using Curve fitting in matlab using the following code to fit a 2-d curve.

```
ft_ = fittype({'x', 'x^0.5', 'x^0.2', 'x^0.8', '1'},'dependent',{'y'},'independent',{'x'},'coefficients',{'a', 'b', 'd', 'e', 'c'});
cf_ = fit(inputs,targets,ft_); %// inputs and targets are column vectors
outputs = cf_(future_inputs); %// future_inputs is also a row vector, outputs is predicted values.
```

I am using a polynomial model and then I am extrapolating the obtained curve to predict future values. I am quite satisfied with my predicted values.

Now, I need some reference to the algorithm being used by matlab in the curve fitting to get the values of corresponding coefficients of the polynomial being used as the model. I have googled but found nothing satisfactory.

I need both reference to some paper that I can quote and to some place where I can understand it easily.

Comment: Have you looked at: http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/curvefit/least-squares-fitting.html?

Comment: @am304 Thanks, I didn't found it on the search , it looks like what I need.
Still reference to some paper may be required. I am not sure as method of least square fitting is quite general and may not require a quote

Comment: The coefficients are solved by least-squares as @am304 pointed out.  The coefficients are for the weighted sums of polynomials.  Check out this really good set of PDF notes, especially page #8 - http://www.seas.ucla.edu/~vandenbe/103/lectures/ls.pdf

Comment: you might be able to open the source file, ctrl+D ? and they usually have extensive documentation for these things.